# Open Zip file and view content (Videos, images, documents) in Rubyonrails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zip

I'm planning to build a Rails app where user can view content of zip-file in their browser without downloading the actual content. Is this possible using RubyonRails? Please guide me a way forward.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can! Take at look at the [rubyzip gem](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip). With it, you could for example get the names of all files contained in the zip as follows

```
zip_filenames = Zip::File.open('foo.zip') do |zip_file|
  zip_file.map { |entry| entry.name } 
end
```

Then use this array to somehow display it in your application. If you'd actually want to open a video/text file contained in the archive, you'll have to extract it on the server to some temporary location, then open it through some other means.